# Rules in String into in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use Pandas to read simple rules in string.

I write this and it's worked :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
a = "(df['col1'] > 1) & (df['col2'] > 3)"

df[eval(a)]
```

But, I would like to remove df[] and '()' in my string value.

I don't know if it's possible, or maybe another way exists to write this.

Thank you

Comment: Look at `df.query`: `df.query('col1 > 1 & col2 > 3')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df
|    |   col1 |   col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  0 |      1 |      3 |
|  1 |      2 |      4 |
>>> a = 'col1 > 1 & col2 > 3'
>>> df.query(a)

|    |   col1 |   col2 |
|---:|-------:|-------:|
|  1 |      2 |      4 |
```